# Is there a way to save & use the cut_bins values from pd.cut() into a different file

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I am using the **pd.cut()** to do binning of a numerical column in df as below

```
train_df['bucket'], cut_bins = pd.qcut(train_df['rank'] , q=10, labels=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], retbins=True)
```

And I can use the **cut_bins** values to bin my test data as well as below,

```
test_df['bucket'] = pd.cut(test_df['rank'], bins=cut_bins, labels=False, include_lowest=True)
```

So, now the situation is that the model was saved as a **.pkl** file. Whenever a new user wants to loads the model how can they use this **cut_bins** value that was gotten from the train_df and do the similar binning in their new_df.

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks,